# In Laravels Eloquent, how do I get records with relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to pull all records that have an event relationship which has an event date of today. I have the following code:

```
    EventStaffStation::with([
        'event' => function($query) {
            $query->where('event_date', Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'));
        }
    ])->where([
        'staff_id' => auth()->user()->id
    ])->has('event')->get()
```

This gives me a record event_staff_stations but it sets the event relationship to null. I want the record to not be returned if the relationship is null.

Basically if event_staff_station record isn't for today then I don't want it returned. I'm only interested in records with an event day of today.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
EventStaffStation::whereHas(
    'event' , function($query) {
        $query->where('event_date', Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'));
    }
)->where([
    'staff_id' => auth()->user()->id
])->get()
```

If you want to get records based on relationship existence/condition you should use `has/whereHas` instead of `with`. Of course in above query you can also add `with` that will eager load any relationship you want if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both `whereHas` and `with`.

`whereHas` will check the existence of the relation and `with` will return record with relationship object.

```
EventStaffStation::whereHas(
    'event' , function($query) {
        $query->where('event_date', Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y'));
    }
)->with('event')
->where([
    'staff_id' => auth()->user()->id
])->get();
```